# What's the equivalent of Delphi's RoundTo() in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-xe

What's the equivalent of Delphi's RoundTo() in C#?

I am not very familiar with Delphi and I am aware of C#'s `Math.Round()` but am not sure how equivalent they are. `Math.Round()` has several overloads and `RoundTo()` has two.

Comment: Why not test it yourself? Or can you list some test cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent method is [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx). You need to use the overload which offers the functionality that you need, whatever that is.

The Delphi `RoundTo` function is not overloaded and is best matched with this overload of [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx):

```
public static double Round(
    double value,
    int digits
)
```